# Send Email using exchange server in .NET 1.1 C#

Tags: email, exchange-server, .net-1.1

I want to know if it's possible to send email in .NET 1.1 C# using exchange server.
I had already looked at System.Web.Mail and CDO and I cannot find information about connecting to exchange and send emails. Use exchange is really mandatory for me, so SMTP is not an option.

Anyone can help me with this?

Thanks in advance,

Paulo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed using CDO 1.2.1 (MAPI)
Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

But Exchange uses SMTP to send the message so I'm not sure what the question is. If you just need to avoid connecting to port 25 on the Exchange server, you can write a text file formatted as an email with all the necessary headers and drop it in the Pickup directory on the Exchange server and it will be sent.